# Kie-workbench drop-down list using enumeration definition

Tags: kie, drools-kie-workbench

I am new in the drools , I want to know how can we use Enumeration definition for list of data as drop down in GDST.

I have done the drop down list in GDST by using option "Add condition" but its a static. I need data in drop-down dynamic data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked in [the documentation There is a part "External data sources in enumerations"](http://Have%20you%20looked%20in%20the%20documentation%20There%20is%20a%20part%20%22External%20data%20sources%20in%20enumerations%22?%20%20'Applicant.region'%20:%20(new%20com.mycompany.DataHelper()).getListOfRegions()%20Have%20a%20look%20you%20have%20what%20you%20need.%20Of%20course,%20you%20have%20to%20package%20you%20java%20code%20in%20a%20maven%20artefact%20that%20you%20add%20as%20a%20dependency%20in%20your%20kjar%20drools%20maven%20artefact%20Regards)?

'Applicant.region' : (new com.mycompany.DataHelper()).getListOfRegions()

Have a look you have what you need. 
Of course, you have to package you java code in a maven artefact that you add as a dependency in your kjar drools maven artefact Regards